# unit test for a file import export module

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to write unit tests for a file import export module.

One of my method checks that a filename passed exists.

How would this be mocked and a test written to check if the file exists or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unit tests are supposed to prove that a unit of code functions correctly in *complete isolation*. If your test depends on the file system to function correctly in order to pass, your test is suboptimal and could be lying to you on any given test run.

Like any experiment, when you have more than one variable in play, you can't be sure of your results. For PHP code that interacts with the file system, it's best to mock the file system using a custom stream wrapper (usually [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream), but you can easily write your own stream wrapper if you really want to).

`$noTest < $testWithFileSystemDependency < $testThatMocksFileSystem`

Usually, this is accomplished by passing file paths into the methods that use them directly:

```
<?php
function myFunction($someFilePath) {
    // do stuff
}
```

In this way, you can mock the file system and pass in a testable dummy path that will behave how you have mocked it to behave.

Comment: Just for clarity, why go all the way with a virtual FS instead of just creating a temporary directory using PHP's own `tempnam()` and friends?

Comment: @Gutza the problem with that is even though it's a temporary file it still depends on the file system functioning correctly to work with it. The point of vfsStream is that your mock "file system" is kept in memory. Another benefit is that when you're dealing with a large test-suite with many tests you can usually significantly speed up the test runs by not hammering the disk all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

You write two tests. One creates the file and expects your method to succeed, the other ensures the file doesn't exist and expects your method to fail.

Comment: Does your function remove the file before exiting?

Comment: The first one does, the second one doesn't. Or, if your setup is conductive, use `setUp()` and `tearDown()` to ensure consistent testing conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I just create `_files` directory in the tests directory and create files there. Or in `/tmp`.

There is a way to mock the fs: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mocking-the-filesystem but from my experience - I prefer real FS operations (in this case).